# MVC5 Where is Principal Read From Cookie?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies

Where and when is the HttpContext.Current.User read from the HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies ?

I have started looking at the ASP.NET MVC 5 source code http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/ and couldn't figure out where principal was first set.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using federated authentication, it is the `SessionAuthenticationModule` that uses its configured `CookieHandler` to deserialize a cookie into a `SessionSecurityToken`.  It then uses the token to create a `ClaimsPrincipal` for the user.  This `ClaimsPrincipal` is then used to set to the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` and `HttpContext.User` properties.  This process takes place in the `AuthenticateRequest` and `PostAuthenticateRequest` steps of the ASP.NET pipeline. Since it is done in the ASP.NET pipeline, I doubt you will find it in the MVC source code.

You can find more info on the `SessionAuthenticationModule` here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.sessionauthenticationmodule%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

[This is a great post](http://leastprivilege.com/2012/02/02/mixing-forms-and-token-authentication-in-a-single-asp-net-application-the-details/) on FormsAuth and FedAuth.  It explains how all the bits fit together in the ASP.NET pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking in the wrong spot. Authentication is now using the OWIN middleware. [This blog is useful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/07/03/understanding-owin-forms-authentication-in-mvc-5.aspx). The source code is in a project called katana. [The source code is here](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/). And [here is the official asp.net blog post](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline)

In short. Owins is new way of processing the http request. The owins request is passed down a pipeline of 'middle ware' which handles the request. The CookieAuthenticationMiddleware from project katana (above) is responsible for decoding the authentication cookie.